# Who are the Far Cry 3 voice actors?

Tags: far-cry-3

A number of reviews so far have praised the voice work in Far Cry 3.

Who are these deserving actors and what other stuff have the leads performed in?
I guess we are talking about Jason Brody and Vaas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMDB.com has [a list of the voice actors for the game](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2321297/).

The main characters you mentioned are voiced by [Gianpaolo Venuta](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0893464/)(Jason Brody) and [Michael Mando](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm3103126/)(Vaas).